# logout customer form observer after validation and add error message

Tags: magento

im a magento newbie, well i have two login forms 1 for regular customer and 1 for customer of type "Wholesale" so i create an observer in which i check that if the user (that trying to log in ) is a Wholesale customer , it log them out it goes like

```
class Hs_Login_Model_Observer {

    public function validateCustomer($observer){
        $c= $observer->getCustomer();
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($c->getId() );
        $customerType = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($c->getId())->getData('customer_group_code');


        if ( $customerType == "Wholesale") {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();   
        }




    }
}
```

and it works but i also want to show an error massage on the login page,

i have tried the layout handle

```
$observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
            ->addHandle('cus_layout handle')
```

i have tried notifications

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->addError(‘Error message’);
```

but nothing seems to b working, need help

Comment: i figure it out, kind of going in wrong direction

i rewrite the post action of AccountController and also update the form.phtml file so i can find which customer is logging from which form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification path is the right one.

The only thing is, the pages linked to the customer account do not display the `core/session` messages but rather the `customer/session` messages.

So this should work :

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
    ->addError(
        Mage::helper('customer')
            ->__('An error occurred')
    ); 
// also useful to remember to make messages translatable via an helper
```

Comment: you are again adding error in customers sessions, when i log out the customer, session  get deleted along with its massage, so still have the same probelm

Comment: The session mechanism to handle messages is not linked to the fact that you have a customer logged in or not, so that's not the reason of you problem. Maybe you actually forget something when you defined your two forms to connect those to the right session storage to display messages. A little more context of the forms and controller your are using is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

1 particular solution that i found is not to use the observer at all,
i just want to keep track that if a "wholesaler customer" is longing from default login page then magneto should give some error,

so i rewrite the AccountController.php

```
    class Hs_Login_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {
        public function loginPostAction() {
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                    $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
                    $regularCustomer;
                    if ($login['form_type'] == "default") {
                         $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
                         $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                         $customer->loadByEmail($login['username']);
                         $customerType = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($customer->getId())->getData('customer_group_code');

                         if ($customerType == "Wholesale") {
                                $session->addError($this->__('invalid username and password'));
                                $this->_loginPostRedirect();
                                return;
                          }
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .


                     }


              } 
        }
    }
```

which is done by configuring magneto to run my class for controlling this route

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                         <Hs_Login before="Mage_Customer">Hs_Login</Hs_Login>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

and set a hidden attribute in form of regular login page

```
 <li>
    <div class="hidden">
      <input type="text" name="login[form_type]" value="default" />
    </div>
</li>
```